# how to make childelemt not move while using resizable

Tags: javascript

I need a place to put a lot of dom cubes and make their js function working,so i decide to make the place a parent div but at the same time i need to resize the place so i can have a bigger or smaller space to put cubes

i tried to use resizable in jqui but when i resizing the left or top side the cubes will move too ,i know it is because of the childelemt is locating by the parent's left or top distance so i tried to use the resizestop event to replace cubes back

this is my code

```
$("#huabu").resizable({
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
    var oldleft=ui.originalPosition.left;
    var newleft=ui.position.left
    var distantleft=parseInt(newleft-oldleft)
    var str = $("#tile_container").css("left")
    var oldleft=parseInt(str.substring(0,str.length-2))
    var moveleft=oldleft-distantleft
    if(distantleft<0){
        $("#tile_container").css({"left":moveleft})
    }
    if(distantleft>0){
        $("#tile_container").css({"left":moveleft})
    }

    var oldtop=ui.originalPosition.top;
    var newtop=ui.position.top
    var distanttop=parseInt(newtop-oldtop)
    var str = $("#tile_container").css("top")
    var oldtop=parseInt(str.substring(0,str.length-2))
    var movetop=oldtop-distanttop
    console.log(movetop)
    if(distanttop<0){
        $("#tile_container").css({"top":movetop})
    }
    if(distanttop>0){
        $("#tile_container").css({"top":movetop})
    }
```

its works well but another problem coming out

1.i found when the place resizing,the childelemt will move with the left or top side but not moving with the right or bottom side,and my code just make sure after resizing the childelemt back,not while resizing,i  wonder how to make it better

2.even its rare to make the place smaller than cubus,but i still want a way to make sure when i resizing the place ,its edge will not through the cubes,i need to say the cubes are draggable so that they can be placed on any where but not over the place

if theres no way to solve them, i also want to know how can i implementate the place,thanks very much